# Does python support fixed size LIFO?

Tags: python

I want a data structure, fixed size LIFO, last in first out. Is it already there?

Edit: Sorry, what I want is LIFO not FIFO.

I checked http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html, it already provides the LIFO, the only thing I want to achieve is automatically drop the oldest one.

Eg) LIFO size 5 with elements: 1 2 3 4 5

After 6 comes in, the 1 should be dropped, becomes:

2 3 4 5 6

How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both [collections.deque](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque) and [queue.Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue) support fifo and a max size.

*Adaptation for clarification from the documentation:*

**queue.LifoQueue** supports this, but will not pop the last one when the determined maxsize has been reached:

> class queue.LifoQueue(maxsize=0)
>
> Constructor for a LIFO queue. maxsize is an integer that sets the
> upperbound limit on the number of items that can be placed in the
> queue. Insertion will block once this size has been reached, until
> queue items are consumed. If maxsize is less than or equal to zero,
> the queue size is infinite.

**collections.deque** will pop the last one as long as maxlen is defined (which is what OP is looking for):

> class collections.deque([iterable[, maxlen]])
>
> If maxlen is not specified or is None, deques may grow to an arbitrary
> length. Otherwise, the deque is bounded to the specified maximum
> length. Once a bounded length deque is full, when new items are added,
> a corresponding number of items are discarded from the opposite end.
> Bounded length deques provide functionality similar to the tail filter
> in Unix. They are also useful for tracking transactions and other
> pools of data where only the most recent activity is of interest.

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is not block the appender. In my case, if the queue is full, it will still be pushed in, replace the oldest one.